# Generate comma separated value based on input in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `Rule_X_ListType` in the following structure

```
Rue_ID  ListType_ID  Value
---------------------------
1       2            319
1       2            400
1       5            8150
1       5            1000
1       3            10211
2       2            400
2       6            10211
3       7            10211
3       3            8051
2       2            319
```

If I will give the input as `Rule_ID = 1 and ListType_ID = 2`, then I need the output as a string with values :

```
319,400
```

Anybody please help out...Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not feel the neccessity for either the CTE or the FOR XML PATH.
This can be accomplished using the much more simple method of COALESCE

```
DECLARE @List varchar(100)

SELECT 
   @List = COALESCE(@List + ', ', '') + CAST(Value AS varchar(10))
FROM 
   Rule_X_ListType
WHERE 
   Rule_ID = 1 and ListType_ID = 2

SELECT @List
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT * FROM Rule_X_ListType WHERE Rue_ID = 1 AND ListType_ID = 2
)
SELECT STUFF
(
   (SELECT ',' + A.Value FROM CTE A ORDER BY A.VALUE FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''
) AS CSVValues
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.Rule_ID,T1.ListType_ID,STUFF(VAL,1,1,'') AS VALUE
FROM Rule_X_ListType T1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT  ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Value)
             FROM Rule_X_ListType T2
         WHERE T1.Rule_ID =T2.Rule_ID and T1.ListType_ID =T2.ListType_ID
         FOR XML PATH(''))A(VAL)
WHERE T1.Rule_ID = 1 and T1.ListType_ID = 2
```

SQL Tips and Tricks in http://sqlbay.blogspot.in/